# How to combine between compose and HTML modes easily in blogger?

Tags: blogger, blog

I need to edit a blogger post to add some HTML snippets, when I switch to the HTML mode it becomes very harsh to find the place I want to add the HTML snippet in, in contrast to the Compose mode, that I use for regular text. Isn't there a way to easily identify the text (as I see it) to add HTML snippets?

Answer (score 1):

In Compose mode, put in some marker text which doesn't appear anywhere else in your post (I usually use XXX) at the place where you want to add the HTML.

Then switch to HTML mode, and use your browser's Find tool  (it's Ctrl/f on Chrome) to locate that marker text.

Add your HTML.

Then switch back to Compose mode, and remove the marker text.